# Using Swift UIActivityViewController to share image from separate Class(viewcontroller)?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a game in swift.  I want a custom image for users to be able to share highscores to Facebook, Twitter etc.

[image: Something like this would be on a separate view controller].

Something like this would be on a separate view controller from where I would share the image from.

I have created this image in a separate view controller.  From my share button, I want to pass the Username, High Score etc for the labels in this separate view controller.  I then want to capture the image(screenshot) of this view controller and using the UIActivityController allow users to share it

This view controller with the high scores should never be displayed.  I just want a image(screenshot) captured of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a view controller for this. Just make a `UIView` that contains the labels and then create an image from the view using something like this:

```
func snapshot(view: UIView) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let screenShot: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: I created a UIView with a .xib extension.  I think created a class to go along with it and hooked up on the labels.  How do I go about using that to create the image.

I tried var image = snapshot(myView)  but that didn't work

Comment: Make sure you are initializing your view from the nib `let yourView: YourCustomView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourNib", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! YourCustomView` then set the frame. Replace `CGSizeMake(100, 100)` in the above code with `yourView.frame.size`.

Comment: You sir are a life saver.  Thank you so much!